# I thought string literal were read only?

Tags: c++

```cpp
char* a = "string"; /*"string" is a string literal, thus modifying
value isn't allowed, but then why */
char b[] = "string1"; /*"string1" is
also a string literal but why modification of this is allowed? */

a[1] = 's'; //this is not allowed b[1] = 'p'; //this is allowed
```

Why can char array be modified when it is clearly pointing to a string literal?

Comment: I believe when you do `char* a = "string"` you get a pointer to the read only memory, but when you do `b[] = "string1"` you get a copy of the string on the stack

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between char s\[\] and char \*s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s)

Comment: The array does not point to anything - arrays are not pointers. It is a copy of the initializer and this works the same as if you wrote `char b[] = {'s','t','r','i','n','g','1','\0'};`.

Comment: The string `"string1"` is a literal, you're right. But `b[]` is not a literal. It is a variable, an array whose size and items' initial values are taken from that literal. So `"string1"` is read-only and `b[]` is not.

Answer (score 5):

> when it is clearly pointing to a string literal?

No. Given `char b[] = "string1";`, `b` is not a pointer pointing to the [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal), but a `char` array containing copy of `"string1"`. The modification on the string literal leads to UB, but modification on the `char` array is fine.

> String literals can be used to [initialize character arrays](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). If an array is initialized like `char str[] = "foo";`, `str` will contain a copy of the string `"foo"`.

BTW `char* a = "string";` is not allowed since C++11; you have to write it as `const char* a = "string";`.